# Swagger not finding ApiVersion-ed actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm building a Web API in ASP.NET Core and am experimenting with multiple versions. I am creating Swagger docs for each version following these instructions: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/README.md#customize-the-action-selection-process

I have 2 versions of the same action defined like this:

```
namespace Web.Api
{
    [ApiController]
    [Area("api")]
    [Route("[area]/[controller]")]
    public abstract class MyApiControllerBase : ControllerBase
    {

    }
}

namespace Web.Api.V1
{
    public class TestController : MyApiControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [ApiVersion("1.0")]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok("Version 1.0 endpoint.");
        }
    }
}

namespace Web.Api.V2
{
    public class TestController : MyApiControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [ApiVersion("2.0")]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok("Version 2.0 endpoint.");
        }
    }
}
```

And my Swagger Gen configured like this in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.DocInclusionPredicate((docName, apiDesc) =>
    {
        if (!apiDesc.TryGetMethodInfo(out MethodInfo methodInfo))
        {
            return false;
        }

        IEnumerable<ApiVersion> versions = methodInfo.DeclaringType
            .GetCustomAttributes(true)
            .OfType<ApiVersionAttribute>()
            .SelectMany(a => a.Versions);

        return versions.Any(v => $"v{v.ToString()}" == docName);
    });

    options.SwaggerDoc("v1.0", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1.0" });
    options.SwaggerDoc("v2.0", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v2.0" });
});
```

However when I visit my Swagger UI it says "No operations defined in spec!" for both v1.0 and v2.0. If I inspect the `DocInclusionPredicate` when loading the Swagger doc it appears that the `ApiVersion` Attribute isn't being picked up and thus explains why they aren't included in the docs. For example, when `Web.Api.V2.TestController.Get` is passed as the `apiDesc` argument, this is what is found for Attributes:

[Attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y76YP.png)

Only `ApiControllerAttribute`, `AreaAttribute`, `RouteAttribute`, and `ControllerAttribute` are found. All of these are Attributes on base classes, not directly on the `TestController` or `Get()` action itself.

Comment: If you open http://localhost:xxx/xxx/swagger.json in your browser, is it accessible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For asp.net core 3.0,you could follow the following steps:

1.Install [`Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.0.0`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/)

2.Install [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning 4.0.0`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning/4.0.0)

3.Install [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer 4.0.0`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer/4.0.0)

4.Change your controller like below(`ApiVersion` needs to be declared on controller):

```
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
public class TestController : MyApiControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]      
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok("Version 1.0 endpoint.");
    }
}
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[ApiVersion("2.0")]
public class TestController : MyApiControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]        
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok("Version 2.0 endpoint.");
    }
}
```

5.Startup.cs(Note that you need to use `services.AddVersionedApiExplorer` and set `options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl=true` to tell swagger to replace the version in the controller route and configure the api version: ):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();

    services.AddApiVersioning(o => {
        o.ReportApiVersions = true;
        o.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
        o.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
    });
    services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(o =>
    {
        o.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
        o.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
    });

    services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
    {
        options.DocInclusionPredicate((docName, apiDesc) =>
        {
            if (!apiDesc.TryGetMethodInfo(out MethodInfo methodInfo))
            {
                return false;
            }

            IEnumerable<ApiVersion> versions = methodInfo.DeclaringType
                .GetCustomAttributes(true)
                .OfType<ApiVersionAttribute>()
                .SelectMany(a => a.Versions);

            return versions.Any(v => $"v{v.ToString()}" == docName);
        });

        options.SwaggerDoc("v1.0", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1.0" });
        options.SwaggerDoc("v2.0", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v2.0" });
    });
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseApiVersioning();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1.0/swagger.json", "V1 Docs");
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v2.0/swagger.json", "V2 Docs");
    });

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```