# Trouble with Swagger' correct configuration in .Net Core 5.0 Application... works, but somethings off

Tags: configuration, swagger, versioning, webapi, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm having a strange issue with Swagger... I'm using versioned APIs and indeed the versioning is working... but, I'm having two issues that I'm confused about.  I've configured for two separate API versions so I can test things out... v1.0 and v2.0.  I've put the attributes for the versioning into both the controllers as well as their actions to mix things up a bit to see if the versioning in Swagger is showing only the endpoints that pertain to each version.

The issues I am having is:
a.) the rendered route in the Swagger output for each endpoint isn't showing in the major.minor format (ie: v1.0) but rather is "/api/v1/...". I would expect the route to be "/api/v1.0/...".  Anyone have an idea how to fix this?
b.) regardless of which API version I select from the dropdown at the top of the page, Swagger is yielding all endpoints (for both v1.0 and v2.0).  I believe the correct functionality would be to filter to only display the endpoints for the selected version, but this isn't happening.

NOTE: in the screenshot below, although I have set all the controller and action versioning attributes to be "v2.0" that they are displayed on the "v1.0" version page.

[Sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X09JH.png)

```
Here is my startup config and example of my controller and actions:

 /// <summary>
    /// Jobs API for CRUD job 
    /// </summary>
    [ApiVersion("1.0")]
    [ApiVersion("2.0")]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
    public class JobsController : Controller
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets all jobs using the API
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Return a list of jobs</returns>
        [ApiVersion("2.0")]
        [HttpGet]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Job>), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok("hello");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// get Job using the id
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id">job id</param>
        /// <returns>Job for the ID</returns>
        [ApiVersion("2.0")]
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Job>), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
        public IActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            if (id == 0)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            //var jobExists = Jobs.Exists(j => j.Id == id);

            //if (jobExists == false)
            //{
            //    return NotFound($"Job with Id not found: {id}");
            //}

            return Ok();
        }
```

Startup:
#region Setup API Versioning Region

```
        // NOTE: declaration order matters for versioning APIs to be setup correctly
        services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(o => // this is required to support swagger gathering info on all of the existing endpoints for ALL versions of APIs
        {
             o.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
             o.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
        });

        services.AddApiVersioning(o =>
        {
            o.ReportApiVersions = true;
            o.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
            o.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
        });

        #endregion 

        #region Swagger Setup Region

        #region Swashbuckle Overview - an automated Swagger content generator -- See: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.WebApi
        //  Seamlessly adds a Swagger to WebApi projects! Combines ApiExplorer and Swagger/ swagger - ui to provide a rich discovery, documentation and playground experience
        //  to your API consumers.
        //  In addition to its Swagger generator, Swashbuckle also contains an embedded version of swagger - ui which it will automatically serve up once Swashbuckle is installed.
        //  This means you can complement your API with a slick discovery UI to assist consumers with their integration efforts.Best of all, it requires minimal coding and maintenance,
        //  allowing you to focus on building an awesome API!
        //  And that's not all ...
        //  Once you have a Web API that can describe itself in Swagger, you've opened the treasure chest of Swagger-based tools including a client generator that can be targeted to a wide
        //  range of popular platforms. See swagger-codegen for more details.
        //
        //  Features:
        //  Auto-generated Swagger 2.0
        //    * Seamless integration of swagger-ui
        //    * Reflection - based Schema generation for describing API types
        //    * Extensibility hooks for customizing the generated Swagger doc
        //    * Extensibility hooks for customizing the swagger - ui
        //    * Out - of - the - box support for leveraging Xml comments
        //    * Support for describing ApiKey, Basic Auth and OAuth2 schemes... including UI support for the Implicit OAuth2 flow
        //
        //  How does Swashbuckle find the endpoints that it needs to document?...
        //      Swashbuckle requires the use of routing attributes to find the endpoints... if you are using conventional routing (as opposed to attribute routing), any controllers and the actions
        //      on those controllers that use conventional routing will not be represented in ApiExplorer, which means Swashbuckle won't be able to find those controllers
        //      and generate Swagger operations from them.  For example:
        //
        //          [Route("example")]
        //          public class ExampleController : Controller
        //
        //  IMPORTANT: Ensure your API actions and parameters are decorated with explicit "Http" and "From" bindings.
        //      [HttpPost]
        //      public void CreateProduct([FromBody] Product product)
        //      ...
        //      [HttpGet]
        //      public IEnumerable<Product> SearchProducts([FromQuery] string keywords)

        //      NOTE: If you omit the explicit parameter bindings, the generator will describe them as "query" params by default.
        //      TIP: to correctly setup versioning in conjunction with Swagger, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60084877/swagger-not-finding-apiversion-ed-actions
        #endregion

        // Add Open API (Swagger) functionality via Swashbuckle -- for full options, see: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/README.md#configuration--customization
        //     TIP: Adding triple-slash comments /// to an action enhances the Swagger UI by adding the description to the section header.
        //     TIP: Add a <remarks> element to the Create action method documentation. It supplements information specified in the <summary> element and provides a more robust Swagger UI. The <remarks> element content can consist of text, JSON, or XML.

        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>  // Configuration documentation -- See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/aspnet/aspnetcore.docs/getstarted-swashbuckle-aspnetcore/?tabs=visual-studio
        {
            // configure swagger to handle versioning, otherwise this error is presented: "No operations defined in spec!"
            c.DocInclusionPredicate((docName, apiDesc) =>
            {
                if (!apiDesc.TryGetMethodInfo(out MethodInfo methodInfo))
                {
                    return false;
                }

                IEnumerable<ApiVersion> versions = methodInfo.DeclaringType
                    .GetCustomAttributes(true)
                    .OfType<ApiVersionAttribute>()
                    .SelectMany(a => a.Versions);

                return versions.Any(v => $"v{v.ToString()}" == docName);
            });

            c.SwaggerDoc("v1.0", new OpenApiInfo
            {
                Version = "v1.0",
                Title = "test Software blah API version 1.0",
                Description = "A RESTful web API to access and manage blah metric reporting.",
                TermsOfService = new Uri("https://test.com/termsofservice"),
                Contact = new OpenApiContact
                {
                    Name = "test Software",
                    Email = "support@test.com",
                    Url = new Uri("https://test.com/apisupport"),
                },
                License = new OpenApiLicense
                {
                    Name = "Use License: CDDL-1.0",
                    Url = new Uri("https://opensource.org/licenses/CDDL-1.0"),
                }
            });
            c.SwaggerDoc("v2.0", new OpenApiInfo
            {
                Version = "v2.0",
                Title = "test Software blah API Version 2.0",
                Description = "A RESTful web API to access and manage blah metric reporting.",
                TermsOfService = new Uri("https://test.com/termsofservice"),
                Contact = new OpenApiContact
                {
                    Name = "test Software",
                    Email = "support@test.com",
                    Url = new Uri("https://test.com/apisupport"),
                },
                License = new OpenApiLicense
                {
                    Name = "Use License: CDDL-1.0",
                    Url = new Uri("https://opensource.org/licenses/CDDL-1.0"),
                }
            });

            // Apply the API versioning filters for swagger
            //c.OperationFilter<SwaggerRemoveVersionFromParameter>();
            //c.DocumentFilter<SwaggerReplaceVersionWithExactValueInPath>();

            c.EnableAnnotations();
            c.ExampleFilters();

            c.OperationFilter<AddHeaderOperationFilter>("correlationId", "Correlation Id for the request", false); // adds any string you like to the request headers - in this case, a correlation id
            c.OperationFilter<AddResponseHeadersFilter>(); // [SwaggerResponseHeader]

            // Set the comments path for the Swagger JSON and UI.
            var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
            var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
            c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);  // standard Swashbuckle functionality, this needs to be before c.OperationFilter<AppendAuthorizeToSummaryOperationFilter>()

            c.OperationFilter<AppendAuthorizeToSummaryOperationFilter>(); // Adds "(Auth)" to the summary so that you can see which endpoints have Authorization
            // or use the generic method, e.g. c.OperationFilter<AppendAuthorizeToSummaryOperationFilter<MyCustomAttribute>>();

            // add Security information to each operation for OAuth2
            c.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();
            // or use the generic method, e.g. c.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter<MyCustomAttribute>>();

            // if you're using the SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter, you also need to tell Swashbuckle you're using OAuth2
            c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Description = "Standard Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. Example: \"bearer {token}\"",
                In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                Name = "Authorization",
                Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey
            });

        });
        services.AddSwaggerExamplesFromAssemblies(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()); // This will register your "examples" with the ServiceProvider.

        #endregion

        // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwagger(); 

        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.), specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1.0/swagger.json", "test API v1.0");
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v2.0/swagger.json", "test API v2.0");
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!  OK...

Credit should go to https://dev.to/htissink/versioning-asp-net-core-apis-with-swashbuckle-making-space-potatoes-v-x-x-x-3po7 and the comment here... https://dev.to/codeswayslay/comment/paff.

Secret sauce is:

a.) decorate your controllers' action methods with the MapToApiVersion Swagger attribute... for example: `[MapToApiVersion("1.0")]`

b.) ensure that your DocInclusionPrediate lambda is setup like this:

```
setup.DocInclusionPredicate((version, desc) => 
                {
                    if (!desc.TryGetMethodInfo(out MethodInfo methodInfo))
                        return false;

                    var versions = methodInfo.DeclaringType
                    .GetCustomAttributes(true)
                    .OfType<ApiVersionAttribute>()
                    .SelectMany(attr => attr.Versions);

                    var maps = methodInfo
                    .GetCustomAttributes(true)
                    .OfType<MapToApiVersionAttribute>()
                    .SelectMany(attr => attr.Versions)
                    .ToArray();

                    return versions.Any(v => $"v{v.ToString()}" == version)
                    && (!maps.Any() || maps.Any(v => $"v{v.ToString()}" == version));
                });
```

Pay close attention to the maps variable as it finds all of the attributes mapped to particular versions... as well as the return assignment shown above.